# ASP.net call javascript then return a value to code behind

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, postback

Hey all I am designing a website in ASP.net from a PHP designed site. They do their form checks via JavaScript and then submit all data via Ajax if it passes validation.

Is it possible to fire off a piece of JavaScript from a submit button via code behind and read the returned value **before** I process to either postback to save the data or do nothing until the user corrects the fields indicated by the JavaScript?

Comment: Yes something like that is indeed possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing the validation in javascript, i would make a hidden submit button that gets clicked by the javascript button if the validation passes:

```
<input type="button" value="validate" onclick="Validate()" />

<asp:Button ID="aspButton" class="aspButton" OnClick="CodeBehindMethod" style="display: none;" />


<script>
function Validate() {
    //if validation passes
    $(".aspButton").click(); //This is the reason for the class on this button, since                       
                             //asp buttons have huge long stupid id names
    //else do some kind of error notification
}

</script>
```

If you are validating in code behind, then why not just use a post back from a submit button?

Comment: Thats a really good idea! I am going to try this one.

Answer (score 1):

in .NET the button control has an onClientClick where you enter any js function or code. word of caution, add return false; after said code, otherwise .net will fire a full postback.

this may be hacky, but you could look into using update panels for this as well; just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do this a number of ways. I prefer handlers because they are super light-weight. Although, it would probably be less work for you to pull their Javascript and use .NET's validators. Here's an example handler though just in case:

```
public class CheckData : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string sInputData = context.Request["input_post_var"];
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sInputData))
            context.Response.Write("1");
        else
            context.Response.Write("0");
    }
}
```

You can create one of these by right-clicking a folder in your solution, Add New Item..., locate Generic Handler.

You can also use AJAX.NET, but really the entire framework is incredibly bloated and I'd avoid it if you can. That's just preference though.